# Unable to build `Dense` layer with non-floating point dtype Error

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently learning Deep learning and Keras. When I am executing this code I am getting weird error: "TypeError: Unable to build `Dense` layer with non-floating point dtype " and I can't figure out what is the problem. What am I missing? How to fix this weird error?

The error show at the model.fit(...

```py
def create_nerual_network():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu)) # Simple Dense Layer
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu)) # Simple Dense Layer
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax))   # Output layer

    return model


train_images, train_labels = load_dataset() #this function works fine
model = create_nerual_network()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs = 15, verbose=2)
train_loss, train_acc = model.evaluate(train_images, train_labels)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is interesting that you do not specify your input shape anywhere before the model compilation but maybe newer versions of Keras can figure this out from provided input.

In which case I am quite certain that the problem is with `train_images`, look at what dtype is this array, it's probably `int8` which is usual format for images as they use 8 bit integers for each color channel.

It is common practice to at least normalize your data before training and always convert it to float.
Try putting this before calling `model.fit`:

```
train_images = train_images / 256.
```

This will normalize your images into range `[0, 1)` and convert it to float array. It is possible that you have to convert to floats also your labels.

Comment: Thanks a lot! adding 'train_images = train_images / 256.' solved the Issue!

Comment: Generally speaking, one just needs to convert the input array to floats. For instance, when using a numpy array, you can proceed with `my_array.astype(float)`.